# Looping through a php array and echo results

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, echo

I have this php function  :

```
<?php
global $searchandfilter;
$sf_current_query = $searchandfilter->get(108542)->current_query()->get_array();
echo '<pre>',print_r($sf_current_query,true),'</pre>';
?>
```

and as a result this multi-level array :

```
Array
(
    [_sft_areas] => Array
        (
            [name] => Areas
            [singular_name] => Area
            [all_items_label] => All Areas
            [type] => taxonomy
            [active_terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 288
                            [name] => LA Zone
                            [value] => la-zone
                            [count] => 18
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 291
                            [name] => Bel Air
                            [value] => bel-air
                            [count] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm gonna get rid of the print_r but I'm struggling to use a foreach function in order to echo something like this :

Areas : LA Zone, Bel Air.

I'm pretty new to php, can anyone help me with that ?

thanks !

Comment: Can there be more `[ _sft_areas]` then this one and more `[active_terms]` then the current 2?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach ( $sf_current_query as $results ) {

    //Check whether to use the single or plural label
    $label = count( $results['active_terms'] ) > 1 ? $results['name'] : $results['singular_name'];

    //Collect all names
    $names = array();
    foreach ( $results['active_terms'] as $result ) {
        $names[] = $result['name'];
    }

    //Print label and comma separated list of names
    if ( !empty( $names ) ) printf( '<p>%s: %s</p>', $label, implode( ', ', $names ) );
}
```

First a `foreach` loop to cycle through the top level of your multi-dimensional array. Which in this case only contains one record: `_sft_areas`

After that the label check counts the number of records in the `active_terms` array using the `count()` function. And then uses that outcome in combination with the PHP [ternary comparison operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to check if the label should be singular or plural.

Then all the names are fetched with another `foreach` loop and placed in a separate array called `$names`. (Also perfectly fine to use the `array_column()` function here.)

And lastly I've printed each label and list of names to a `<p>` element using the `printf()` function, but you can use any kind of output you like. The `implode()` function lets you create a string from an array using a separator. In this case it creates a comma separated list from the `$names` array.

Comment: If this answer works for you could you mark the answer as accepted and possibly vote it up? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop to get more than `name` etc. just look at the structure and loop the innermost that you need:

```
foreach($sf_current_query['_sft_areas']['active_terms'] as $terms) {
    echo $terms['name'];
}
```

Or just extract the names and implode them:

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($sf_current_query['_sft_areas']['active_terms'], 'name'));
```